# showing "loading..." text - only one jquey.ajaxSend() for all divs in the document

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

How can I show a "loading..." text ONLY into the div that calls jquery.load().

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //only one ajaxSend for all divs
    $(document).ajaxSend(function()
    {
        $(this).html('LOADING...'); //'this' doesn't works
    });

    //...

    $("#ranking-content").load("content/ranking.php");
    $("#empleados-content").load("content/empleados.php");
    //... more and more

});
```

Inside the ajaxSend callback, how can I get the div's ID that made that ajax request?

I'm sure that there is a better way than doing one ajaxSend per div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To customize the behavior for a particular div, use the [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function:

Define `beforeSend` (script to run before the ajax call) and `context` (the HTML element):

```
$.ajax({
  context: $('#ranking-content'),
  url: 'content/ranking.php',
  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    $(this).html('Loading');
  }
}).done(function (data) {
  $(this).html(data);
});
```

Using this `ajaxSend` isn't needed. You can re-use this code by merging the parameters to ajax with settings supplied by a caller.